# Merge strings together that contain underscores

Tags: java

How do you merge strings together with underscores involved by replacing underscores in the same spot as characters in another string. This function is from a socket hangman game i am making

ie
chicken:

c__c___

__i____

my current code does:
c__c_____i____

desired result:
c_ic___

i've experimented with .replaceall() however it bugs in words where letter doubleup

```
public static void strip(String input){
  String newBlank = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    if (word.charAt(i) == input.charAt(0)){
      newBlank += input.charAt(0);
    } else if(blank.contains(word)){
      newBlank += guess.charAt(i);
    } else {
      newBlank += '_';
    }
  }
//Had replace all here
  blank = newBlank.replace("_", "");
```

If i have `blank = newBlank.replace("_", "");` words like 'apple' work because it has double letters next to each other 'pp' however words like chicken end up being 'cchiken'.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve? I don't understand based on which rules `chicken` should be transformed to `c_ic___`.

Comment: function from a hangman game takes a users input in

Comment: Is there possibility that your strings will look like `a__` `b__`? If yes then what should be result?

Comment: you're adding to the string with the ```+=```, not modifying it...  You need to change the character in that slot to an underscore.  Look into the ```toCharArray()``` method of string, then you can recreate the string by just using ```+```.

Comment: @Madi I implemented a Hangman game and did something similar, but didn't create two different strings. I had a char array which had an "_" underscore for each character, and just modified the characters in the array using index and converting back to string when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = "c__c___";
String str2 = "__i____";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i<Math.max(str1.length(), str2.length()); i++) {

  char ch1 = str1.length() >= i ? '_' : str1.charAt(i);
  char ch2 = str2.length() >= i ? '_' : str2.charAt(i);

  char result;
  if (ch1 == '_')
      result = ch2;
  else
      result = ch1;

  output.append(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: targeted at questioner's apparent expertise level.

Pseudocode for one way of doing this:

```
let length = max(length of input1, length of input2)
let output = new char[length]
for values of i from 0 to length {
   if input1[i] != '_'
      output[i] = input1[i] // non-underscore from input1
   else
      output[i] = input2[i] // non-underscore or underscore
return output converted to array
```

If `input1` and `input2` are different lengths, you'll need to add code to the `if` conditions to prevent array-out-of-range errors.

There are many ways to adapt this pseudocode into Java; start with whichever ways you already know of constructing strings or lists of characters. I can see a neat way of doing it with Streams, but this is for more advanced Java programmers. Have fun trying different ways.

Comment: are there anyway to implement that mid function or will it be better to implement that independently